# how to display dynamic value without using foreach loop in laravel

Tags: laravel, menu, rbac

How to print these type of data in laravel.I am trying to create dynamic menu and these type of problem occurs.Code is like this. my code is like this.
In view composer.

```
 public function compose(View $view)
{
    $menus = $this->menu->getDynamicMenus();

    $user_role = $this->role->lists('name', 'id');
    //dd($user_role);
    $view->with('user_role', $user_role)->with('menus', $menus);
}

menurepository code.

 public function getDynamicMenus()
{
    $user = $this->auth->user();

    $roles = $user->roles;

//        dd($roles);
        $menus = [];
        foreach ($roles as $role) {
//dd($role);
            foreach ($role->menus as $menu) {

                if ($menu["parent_id"] > 0) {
                    $menus[$menu["parent_id"]][$menu["id"]] = $menu->toArray();
                } else {
                    $menus[$menu["id"]] = $menu->toArray();
                }
            }
        }
       // dd($menus);
        return $menus;
    }


and i print in frontend like.

      @foreach($menus as $menu)

                   {{-- {!! Form::open() !!}
                    {!! Form::select('menus',$menus) !!}
                                        {!! Form::close() !!}--}}
                    {{--{!! $menuitem->menu_name !!}--}}
                    {!! $menu->menu_url !!}


                    @endforeach
```

and it shows problem:

```
    Trying to get property of non-object (View: E:\xampp\htdocs\basicwc\resources\views\layouts\partials\sidebar.blade.php) (View: E:\xampp\htdocs\basicwc\resources\views\layouts\partials\sidebar.blade.php) (View: E:\xampp\htdocs\basicwc\resources\views\layouts\partials\sidebar.blade.php)

as  menu are getting in array like in image.
any help??
```

i tried to do like:

```
    {!! menu($menus) !!}

but it says undefined problem.
```

[image]

I added another menu and it's structure is like this:

[image: I added another menu and it's structure is like this:]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access it like an array:

```
@foreach($menus as $menu)

...
{{ $menu['menu_name'] }}
{{ $menu['menu_url'] }}

@endforeach
```

Comment: Undefined index: menu_name 
as menu_name is therer